# Facebook conversions API integration on Squarespace site

Tags: facebook, squarespace, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-conversions-api

We are helping a client who had a recent site redesign done on Squarespace.

With the iOS 14 update the client is worried about not being able to track Apple users for facebook ads.

One solution talked about is to implement the Facebook Conversions API where the Squarespace site would capture data for users that didn't block and we'd get it sent into the Facebook CAPI via a site like Zapier.

There is debate on Squarespace forums whether this is even worth it.

Our developers have not been able to find a clear way to get it done.

Anyone have experience doing this and if so, have then seen that it is worth it?

Thanks!

Jonathon